# Is there a spell that you can leave behind that calls your attention across planes when disturbed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, d20-system

I want to have something that my level 15 wizard can hand to someone saying "Open this box, touch the stone inside and I'll know this town is in trouble."
Alarm (mental) would do that but only if I am within 1 mile. Is there a stronger version of alarm that can do it? Or could limited wish get it done?

The wizard in question will be in his demiplane most of the time, so reaching him there needs to be possible.

It is a Pathfinder character but through spell research and usage of limited wish other D20 games options would be ok, too. The Wizard has permanency in his book to help with short duration spells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the scenario to play out exactly like you're imagining, the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell *watchware* [abjur] (*Unapproachable East* 53) does pretty much precisely what you describe. The spell's cast on an object and

> When that object is damaged, moved, or touched at any later time, you are instantly aware of the fact. If another creature physically touches the object, you also receive a mental image of the creature, which counts as firsthand knowledge of the creature should you later choose to cast *scrying* or a similar spell on that creature.

The signal has no range limit, apparently functioning across planes, and the spell's effect is permanent until the object is fiddled with.

In *Pathfinder*, it's likely the path of least resistance is the spell [*sending*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sending) held within a [*ring of spell storing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-spell-storing). (There are less expensive alternatives to the *ring* like a simple scroll, but anyone can use the *ring*.) Then, to familiarize the *sending* spell's caster with the wizard, have the inside of the box contain a description of the wizard. (To avoid the *ring* becoming treasure, the wizard will likely recast the *sending* spell into the *ring* and mandate the *ring* be returned to the box after the crisis is averted.)

Comment: Note 1: "If the creature in question is not on the same plane of existence as you are, there is a 5% chance that the sending does not arrive. (Local conditions on other planes may worsen this chance considerably.)", so this isn't a 100% solution (unless there are several such rings...)

Comment: Note 2: [Greater Instant Summons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/instant-summons) can allow another creature to summon an object across planes. That, combined with an alarm cast on an object in your demi-plane, can be used to create a 'dimensional alarm' - which will trigger when the object vanishes from the demi-plane...

Comment: @G0BLiN O, I know, and it also won't work in an *antimagic field*, but it's close enough to get the job done 95% of the time, which is, usually, sufficient. I aimed for simple, but I support a complicated and exclusively *Pathfinder* alternative answer.

Comment: Why I accepted this answer: Not only gave it a pure Pathfinder option but a spell that does just what I want done, too that is from a system that is closely related. For me a D&D3.5 5th level sor/wiz spell is perfect because I feel it fits the last option of limited wish: "Produce any other effect whose power level is in line with the above effects" with above effects including 6th level sorc/wiz spells. So even if rating it a level higher in PF it would fit.